# Erros na validação do servidor do Django?

Tags: aplicação-web, django, servidor

Estou colocando o manage.py runserver e dá esses erros na pasta do site packges. Já aconteceu com vocês?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo traceback de erros que você postou, é possível ver que você está usando Python 3.6.x, correto?

Você não especificou qual versão do Django está usando, mas, de qualquer forma, o `HTMLParseError` foi descontinuado no python 3.3 e removido de vez no python 3.5.

Então a sugestão fica em, uma das duas:

- fazer upgrade (subir) do sua versão do Django
- fazer downgrade ("descer") sua versão do Python

Comment: A solução foi baixar a versão do Python (estava com a 3.6 agr 3.4). Mas ainda assim foram encontrado alguns erros, mas nada tão espantoso de se arrumar, vlw pela dica.

Comment: bom saber @DanielMarques - agradeço se puder aceitar a resposta e marcar como válida